# how detect if the message fails on XMPP Smack to Android?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, smack

I making a android chat app. Im use the api level 23, the Xmpp Smack lib version 4.1.8, and on server I use ejabberd, version 16.06.
I use this code to build a XMPP connection.
(TIMEOUT = 5000)

```
   private void buildConnection() {
   XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
           .setServiceName(mServiceName)
           .setHost(mServiceName)
           .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT)
           .setResource("Smack")
           .setUsernameAndPassword(mUsername, mPassword)
           .setSendPresence(true)
           .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
   mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build());

   mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(TIMEOUT);
   chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
   chatManager.addChatListener(this);
   PingManager pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
   pingManager.setPingInterval(5);
   pingManager.registerPingFailedListener(this);

   ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
   reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
   mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);

   if (mConnection != null) {
        DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
                updateMessageStatusReceived(receipt);
                Log.i(TAG, "Confirmation stanza Got: " + receipt);
           }
       });
   }
```

}

(the updateMessageStatusReceived(receipt) method is only to refresh the view).

after that, I connect and authenticate.

Everthing is normal, but when the connection is down, I need to resend the failed messages when the connection is restored. I didn't find any solution or event in Smack to detected if a message fails. Sometimes the delay of confirmation server stanza is high, and my app assumes that message fails but don't, and the other side receive many times the same message.

I build a Message object and send using this code:

```
try {
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(chatMessage.getJid());
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the connection is lost and I send message, no one exception is throw.

my question is: How I know the message realy fail, to try again?
Thanks, and sorry about the english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370499/how-can-i-make-use-of-xmpp-xep-0184-message-delivery-receipts-with-smack

Comment: use XEP-184 and XEP-198.